# Android App that logs in to HTTPS ASPX page

Tags: java, android, asp.net, http

Just to make things clear, I have virtually no experience in HTTP. This project is very ambitious for me, but I am willing to learn in order to be able to accomplish it. I have done some searching for examples across the net, but I can't seem to find an adequate solution. I am aware of terms like GET and POST and understand the basic way to programmatically interact with a website.

Basically, the company I'm working with has a website with a database of clients that I can login to. For starters, I just want to be able to write an Android app that is able to login to the main page with my Username and Password. The site has a login URL of https://"app.companysite.com"/Security/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fDefault.aspx and has a certificate that is for the following purpose: "Ensures the identity of a remote computer".

Is what I'm doing possible? Eventually I would like to be able to open up a Client page and edit their data and re-submit it, but one step a time.

It would be awesome if you could either point me in the direction of some relevant reading material or source code that could help me accomplish my goal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but the way I did my logins is just for justification. So What I did (since I am assuming the verification is done through a MySQL database) is to create a php file that just verifies the login username and passwords are correct and print out a "correct" or "Yes" otherwise just a "No" or "invalid". Something like this :

```
php
//Connects to your Database

      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      //make your mysql query if the username and password are in the database
      //if there is a an approval
     $approval = 1 
     //otherwise
     $approval = 0

    if ($approval > 0) {
       echo "correct";
    } else {
       echo "invalid";
    }

    ?>
```

Now in Android you could make this request to call this website and return the output like the following :

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
//make a timeout for the connections in milliseconds so 4000 = 4 seconds                    httpParameters.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
int timeoutConnection = 4000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 4000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your website URL");

// Add your data
String username = "your username";
String password = "your password";

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

String lines = "";
String data = null;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

while((lines = in.readLine()) != null){
    data = lines.toString();
    al.add(data);
}
in.close();

//To get the response
if(al.get(0).equals("correct")){
      //Your login was successful
}
else {
    //Your login was unsuccessful
}
```

I hope this helped you a bit and pointed you in the right direction.